# Prove that $S^1{\setminus\{(1,0)\}}$ is homeomorphic to $]0,1[$

Tags: general-topology

I'm currently working on this book called "Topology Without Tears".
One of the exercises on the chapter of non-homeomorphic spaces. I'm asked to prove that $S^1{\setminus\{(1,0)\}}$ is homeomorphic to $]0,1[$, but I couldn't find any homeomorphism.  Plus I was told that I should use the stereographic projection On $\mathbb{R}$, but I don't know what that is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about $f : ]0,1[ \rightarrow \mathcal{S}^1$ defined by
$$f(t)=(\cos(2\pi t),\sin(2\pi t)) \quad ?$$

(where you see $\mathcal{S}^1$ as the subset $\lbrace (x,y), x^2+y^2=1 \rbrace \subset \mathbb{R}^2$)